# Using Google code formatter in Eclipse with GWT

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, code-formatting, google-eclipse-plugin

I would like to use the  [Google code style guidelines](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html#s4.4-column-limit) as an Eclipse code formatter.  So, I imported [this formatter](https://github.com/HPI-Information-Systems/Metanome/wiki/Installing-the-google-styleguide-settings-in-intellij-and-eclipse) XML definition file.

However, it disrupts GWT comments, which in my code start at the end of the line with `/* -{` and continue on to multiple lines. The formatter pushes all these lines to the right margin.

[image: GWT comments pushed to right]

I  set `-{ }-`  as "on-off tags."

[image: GWT in-comment tags]

I  also edited the formatter to not format any comments.

[image: No comment-formatting]

However, this misformatting still occurs.

How can I use the Google code-style but still keep GWT comments as-is?

Comment: I also would like to know. As a workround, I usually end up manually selecting the Java bits and using the formatter to format them. If you consolidate all your Javascript native methods (e.g. by moving them to the end of the class), it's not too much hassle.

Comment: Did you try eclipse Checkstyle Plug-in ? You can install it from the eclipse market place. It works well for me, I haven't tried it with GWT though..

Comment: for me the formatting works, even without setting the formatter on/off. can you paste a complete example of the native method code that gets formatted??

Comment: @Shashidhar thank you, I will try that.

Comment: @tobika I'll try that, though it may take a few days.

Comment: just post seomthing like "public static native void yourMethod() /*-{
   //Javascript here
        }-*/;" So i can see the formatting

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the GWT Plugin for Eclipse (or the Google Plugin for Eclipse) and open Java source files with the GWT-aware editor. That way, JSNI is no longer seen as a simple comment and is formatted as JavaScript (using the JS formatter settings)

Comment: Thanks, I actually do have that. But apparently the Google formatter (the XML definition) which I found (separately from the plugin for Eclipse) is not JNSI-aware.  Manually setting on/off tags does not work.I am using another formatter which does deal with it.

Comment: Hmm, are you sure this is related to the formatting definitions and not the editor? (right click, Open With…, GWT editor) If you see JSNI as comments, without syntactic coloration, then AFAICT you're not using the right editor. Now, formatting the whole project might behave differently.

Comment: My goal is to autoformat the Java code. For this I am using a 'formatter'.